# Check if checkbox needs to be checked with a callback function

Tags: angularjs

I want to check if a checkbox element needs to be checked with a callback and set the attribute accordingly. (Angular v1.4.7)I use ng-init to set the state but it is not setting the checks to "checked" cuurently. Any hints?

```
angular.module('vpWidgets', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngSanitize']) 
     .controller('ShiftWidgetCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.isInCookie = function(item){
                return true
            }
 })

 <label class="filter" ng-repeat="country in countries">
     <input id="filter-{{ country.slug }}" type="checkbox" value="{{ country.name }}"
         ng-click="toggleCountryAndArea(country.slug)"
         ng-class="{ 'country': selectedCountryAndArea.indexOf(country.slug) > -1 }"
         ng-init="isChecked = isInCookie(country)" [checked]="isChecked">{{ country.name }}
 </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

got it myself. I needed to use ng-checked.

```
<label class="filter" ng-repeat="country in countries">
    <input id="filter-{{ country.slug }}" type="checkbox" value="{{ country.name}} 
        ng-click="toggleCountryAndArea(country.slug)"
        ng-class="{ 'country': selectedCountryAndArea.indexOf(country.slug) > -1 }"
        ng-checked="isInCookie(country)">{{ country.name }}
</label>
```